# I built a function to calculate a price of an item each year. But my function won't read one of it's variable

Tags: dart

I created a function to calculate the selling price of an item. Each year, the price of the item will decrease by 3/4 of its original price. The problem with my function is it doesn't want to read the year variable regardless of its value. My function always returns 60000000. Can someone please tell me what's wrong with it?

```dart
int add(double year, double price) {
  int i = 0;
  while (i < year) {
    double final_price = price * 3 / 4;
    i++;
    return final_price.round();
  }
}

void main(List<String> arguments) {
  double x = 3;
  double y = 80000000;

  int result = add(x, y);
  print(result);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about the `return` statement inside the `while` loop? Right now, your loop will always only run once since you are returning from the inside instead of outside the loop.

Comment: do you get any errors in log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int add(double year, double price) {
  int i = 0;
  double final_price=price;  // change 1
  while (i < year) {
    final_price = final_price* 3 / 4; // change 2
    i++;
  }
  return final_price.round(); // change 3
}

void main(List<String> arguments) {
  double x = 3;
  double y = 80000000;

  int result = add(x, y);
  print(result);
}
```

Here you go. Returning a value from inside the while loop will stop the function execution on the first traversal only.

Also you need to make final price equal to price because `final_price`'s value is not being changed as price remains same and `i` increases.

Answer (score 0):

what actually are you to trying to do ?
I fixed your code

```
int add(double year, double price) {
  int i = 0;
   double final_price = 0 ; 
  while (i < year) {
    double f = price * 3 / 4;
    i++;
    final_price = f ; 
   
  }
   return final_price.round();
}

void main() // you try to pass an arguments that never used I remove it 
{
  double x = 3;
  double y = 800000;

  int result = add(x, y);
  print(result);
}
```